# Can't train hypergan on mac

Tags: python

Recently I have been trying to run hypergan to test out the features for a project. Everytime I try to start training in a small test folder it has an error. I cd into the folder and typed this command:

```
hypergan train . -s 16x16x3 -f png -b 32 --sample_every 500 --config mymodel.json
```

this is the error it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/hypergan", line 67, in <module>
    config = hc.Selector().load(config_filename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hyperchamber/selector.py", line 112, in load
    content = open(filename)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to take the training data from a folder called "." Is this what you're trying to achieve? Because the error is related to "filename". Try this:

`hypergan train foldername -s 16x16x3 -f png -b 32 --sample_every 500 --config mymodel.json`

You'll need to change the folder, so try replacing foldername with the **location** of the folder, like `Users/mainuser/documents/trainingdata`.